# Обязательно ли делать Client.Disconect(boolean flag) перед закрытием программы? (C#, MailKit, MimeKit)

Tags: c#, client, mailkit

Обязательно ли делать Client.Disconect(boolean flag) перед закрытием программы?

```
    private void FormClose(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        _token = new CancellationToken(true);
        /*_clientProfile.Client.Disconnect(true); нужно ли делать */
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: По-хорошему, для работы с каким-либо источником внешних данных нужно создавать отдельный класс, а в нем реализовывать интерфейс `IDisposable`. Но, в общем случае да, лучше закрыть соединение, если вы не сделали этого ранее.

Comment: @Bulson если добавляю Disconnect вылетает ошибка
`Необработанное исключение: System.InvalidOperationException: The ImapClient is currently busy processing a command in another thread. Lock the SyncRoot property to properly synchronize your threads.` Как исправить подскажите.

Comment: @Denis в сообщении исключения написано решение проблемы: Lock the `SyncRoot` property to properly synchronize your threads.

Comment: @Nikita подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать в моем коде. Я посмотрел [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.hashtable.syncroot(v=vs.110).aspx) и чет не понял как это сделать в своем коде [GitHub](https://github.com/DenisGlod/emailclient).

Comment: @Denis вы что-то совсем не в ту степь пошли. `Hashtable` из BCL никак не относится к этому исключению и к MailKit вообще.

Comment: @Denis я думаю, что нужно сделать как-то так: `lock (imapClient.SyncRoot) { imapClient.Disconnect(true); }`

Comment: @Nikita Спасибо)

Comment: @Nikita lock (imapClient.SyncRoot) { imapClient.Disconnect(true); }
Опять ошибка `ServiceNotConnectedException: The ImapClient is not connected.`

Comment: @Denis ну значит соединение уже было закрыто. Поставьте проверку, что если соединение уже закрыто, то дисконнектиться не требуется. (логично же)

Comment: @Nikita все исправил ошибка была в том что я в другом методе пытался закрыть папку когда клиент уже дисконектнулся